# Changing PYTHONPATH from inside VIM

Tags: command-line, external-command, bash

Today I was writing code in VIM and wanted to change the PYTHONPATH and so I ran:

```
:!echo $PYTHONPATH;export PYTHONPATH="/home/oli/git/published_libraries/computer_communication_framework";echo $PYTHONPATH
:/home/oli/git/whole_cell_modelling_suite:/home/oli/git/cluster_control:/home/oli/git/whole_cell_modelling_suite:/home/oli/git/cluster_control
/home/oli/git/published_libraries/computer_communication_framework

Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

as expected but checking the PYTHONPATH again shows that the change has not been remembered:

```
:!echo $PYTHONPATH
:/home/oli/git/whole_cell_modelling_suite:/home/oli/git/cluster_control:/home/oli/git/whole_cell_modelling_suite:/home/oli/git/cluster_control

Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Can anyone tell me what is going on here and how I can set the PYTHONPATH from inside VIM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your change happened inside a subprocess you spawned from vim. It is not visible to the parent process.

You *might* be able to

```
:let $PYTHONPATH='whatever_you_want'
```

But it is probably a better idea to adjust the environment in the shell and launch vim

```
# export PYTHONPATH=...
# vim ...
```

As pointed out in comments, you can set environment variables only for a single process using `env`:

```
# env PYTHONPATH=... vim
```

Or with bash:

```
# PYTHONPATH=... vim
```

Comment: Single command version: `# PYTHONPATH=... vim ...` ... especially if you only want this modification for a vim session.

Comment: @BLayer agreed, or even with `env`.

Comment: Actually, if you're not using Bash then you'd have to use `env` so it's good to mention it. In Bash, though, using `X=Y mycmd ...` starts just one process for the command while using `env` adds the avoidable overhead of starting a second process.